# Must a $R$-automorphism on $R[X]$ be of the form $X\mapsto aX+b,\ a\in R^*,b\in R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring. I wonder if every $R$-automorphism (that is, a ring automorphism that fix $R$) $\varphi$ of $R[X]$ satisfies $\varphi(X)=aX+b$, where $a$ is an unit in $R$ and $b$ an arbitrary element of $R$.

I can prove that it holds when $R$ is reduced, that is, having no nonzero nilpotent element.

Comment: This question has been solved at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/201573/structure-of-textaut-rrx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, at least if $R$ is not reduced: if $R=\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$,  the $R$-homomorphism $f$ defined by $f(x)=2X^2+X$ is its own inverse since $\,f (f(X))=X$.

Comment: Could you please give a thorough description of  $\text{Aut}_R(R[X])$? For example, is $X\mapsto f(X)(x-a)$ (the constant term of $f$ is invertible and coefficients of other terms are nilpotent) always a $R$-automorphism?

Comment: I don't have  a thorough description, and I'm not sure such a description exists, but the answer to your question is *yes*. I'll try to give a justification in a moment.

Comment: I've proved that the image of $X$ under an automorphism must be of this form. So if my guess is true, we get a thorough description. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's tougher than I thought — at least for me. I don't have the time  at the moment to work on it, but I keep it on my to-do list.

Comment: Brilliant: +1 !

Comment: @georges elencwajg: this was the obvious example